# Device not seen as attached magnetic swiper iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

SoI have a device (unimag II) attached using their api I redid some of their methods to be compatible with the way I want my app to flow and run. However I now am running into issues such as `[UM Info] SDK: initialized` `UM Warning] StartSwipe: UMRET_NO_READER`  as well as the `swipe starting` not being hit when other notifications are. Clearly I am missing something but I have blown so much time on this that I have no clue what I possibly could miss since I made sure that I was as close to their sample app as possible.  Obviously there is more code but this is where it should be getting set as opened I would think

```
-(void)enableSwipe:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{


[self umsdk_activate];
 UmRet ret = [uniReader requestSwipe];
 [self displayUmRet: @"Starting swipe task" returnValue: ret];


}


-(void) umsdk_registerObservers:(BOOL) reg {
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

//list of notifications and their corresponding selector
const struct {NSString __unsafe_unretained *n; SEL s;} noteAndSel[] = {
    //
    {uniMagAttachmentNotification       , @selector(umDevice_attachment:)},
    {uniMagDetachmentNotification       , @selector(umDevice_detachment:)},
    //
    {uniMagInsufficientPowerNotification, @selector(umConnection_lowVolume:)},
    {uniMagMonoAudioErrorNotification   , @selector(umConnection_monoAudioError:)},
    {uniMagPoweringNotification         , @selector(umConnection_starting:)},
    {uniMagTimeoutNotification          , @selector(umConnection_timeout:)},
    {uniMagDidConnectNotification       , @selector(umConnection_connected:)},
    {uniMagDidDisconnectNotification    , @selector(umConnection_disconnected:)},
    //
    {uniMagSwipeNotification            , @selector(umSwipe_starting:)},
    {uniMagTimeoutSwipeNotification     , @selector(umSwipe_timeout:)},
    {uniMagDataProcessingNotification   , @selector(umDataProcessing:)},
    {uniMagInvalidSwipeNotification     , @selector(umSwipe_invalid:)},
    {uniMagDidReceiveDataNotification   , @selector(umSwipe_receivedSwipe:)},
    //
    {uniMagCmdSendingNotification       , @selector(umCommand_starting:)},
    {uniMagCommandTimeoutNotification   , @selector(umCommand_timeout:)},
    {uniMagDidReceiveCmdNotification    , @selector(umCommand_receivedResponse:)},
    //
    {uniMagSystemMessageNotification    , @selector(umSystemMessage:)},

    {nil, nil},
};

//register or unregister
for (int i=0; noteAndSel[i].s != nil ;i++) {
    if (reg)
        [nc addObserver:self selector:noteAndSel[i].s name:noteAndSel[i].n object:nil];
    else
        [nc removeObserver:self name:noteAndSel[i].n object:nil];
   }
}

-(void) umsdk_activate {

//register observers for all uniMag notifications
[self umsdk_registerObservers:TRUE];

NSLog(@"activating");
//enable info level NSLogs inside SDK
// Here we turn on before initializing SDK object so the act of initializing is logged
[uniMag enableLogging:TRUE];

//initialize the SDK by creating a uniMag class object
uniReader = [[uniMag alloc] init];

/*
 //set SDK to perform the connect task automatically when headset is attached
 [uniReader setAutoConnect:TRUE];
 */

//set swipe timeout to infinite. By default, swipe task will timeout after 20 seconds
[uniReader setSwipeTimeoutDuration:0];

//make SDK maximize the volume automatically during connection
[uniReader setAutoAdjustVolume:TRUE];

//By default, the diagnostic wave file logged by the SDK is stored under the temp directory
// Here it is set to be under the Documents folder in the app sandbox so the log can be accessed
// through iTunes file sharing. See UIFileSharingEnabled in iOS doc.
[uniReader setWavePath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"/Documents/audio.caf"]];
}
```